# How to specify 4 connection strings in azurerm_app_service resource block

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a module  defined in our enterprise for creating App Service Plan along with Azure Web Apps. But now i would like to use the "azurerm_app_service" resource block as mentioned in the link : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service
In our module the connection strings are defined under the argument :

```
app_settings = {
   AzureAd__ClientSecret            = <Connection String of the App SP stored in Azure KV>
   DbConnection__ConnectionString   = <Azure SQL DB Connection String stored in Azure KV>
   CosmosDb__Account                = <Connection String of the Cosmos DB Account stored in Azure KV>
   CosmosDb__Key                    = <Connection String of the Cosmos DB Account Key stored in Azure KV>
}
```

Now in the resource block for "azurerm_app_service" as per the URL above there is an argument called connection_string as shown in the URL :

```
connection_string {
    name  = "Database"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = "Server=some-server.mydomain.com;Integrated Security=SSPI"
  }
```

So i would like to know as to how i can define my 4 connection strings in the resource block against the "connection_string" argument and what are the types i should choose for each of my connection strings?
Will it be ok if i continue to define my connection strings as they are in the module now under "app_settings", or that will be a problem if i do that in the new resource block structure?

Looking for some help on this

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any responses.

Comment: Yes it worked.Thanks

Comment: Well, if it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use the [dynamic](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) block to define the multiple connection_string in the `azurerm_app_service` resource block. The example code here for you:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "webapp" {
  ...

  dynamic "connection_string" {
    for_each = var.connection_strings
    content {
      name = each.value.name
      type = each.value.type
      value = each.value.value
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

So you see, you'd better use a variable to configure all the necessary things of the connection_strings, and then use it in the dynamic block.